# How to import .txt to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How do I import a .txt file into a MySQL table?

My .txt file is like this...

```
ex : AF0856427R1  000002200R HADISUMARNO            GGKAMP MALANG WET 3   6   00705    AFAAADF16000-AD-FA P00.001.0  1 000001.00022947.70023290.00 T511060856425A 022014B
```

There are 39 fields in my file.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and any errors you are getting.  We're not here to do all the work.

Comment: Are the fields determined by position on the line or are the spaces field terminators?

Comment: i have tried, and succesfully. but just include on one fields of table. by using LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' insert INTO TABLE name_table ;

Comment: non all of fields terminate by space. so must partitions using strln? ex :AF0856427R1 must partition to 2 fields become AF0856427 and R1..

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysqlimport` command

name of the text file should be the name of the table in which you want the data to be imported. For eg, if your file name is `patient.txt`, data will be imported into `patient` table

```
mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile
```

There are lot of options that you can pass in. [Documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html)

Comment: i have tried, and succesfully. but just include on one fields of table. by using LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' insert INTO TABLE name_table ;

Answer (score 0):

Especially since some of your fields are terminated by spaces and some are based on string length, I would definitely first do some string manipulation with your favorite tool (sed, awk, and perl are all likely very good choices).

Create an intermediary comma separated file. If you have commas in the existing file, you can easily use some other character. The goal is to create a file that has one consistent separator.

You've used the phpMyAdmin tag, so from your table go to the Import tab, select the file, and pick CSV from the dropdown of file types. Edit the options according to what your file looks like (for instance, perhaps § is your column separator and you might leave the next two options blank). Then try the import and check the data to make sure it all arrived in the columns you expected.

Good luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much.. I have tried by another method. using php script => substr(buffer,__,__). but still error.. can help me please?

Comment: Revise your question and show what you did, what the output was, and what the new error message is.